# Python UDF function in Redshift always return NULL value

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, unaccent

I want to have a function in Redshift that removes accents from words. I have found a question in SO([question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string)) with the code in Python for making it. I have tried a few solutions, one of them being:

```
import unicodedata
def remove_accents(accented_string):
    nfkd_form = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', input_str)
    return u"".join([c for c in nfkd_form if not unicodedata.combining(c)])
```

Then I create the function in Redshift as follows:

```
create function remove_accents(accented_string varchar)
returns varchar
immutable
as $$
import unicodedata
def remove_accents(accented_string):
    nfkd_form = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', input_str)
    return u"".join([c for c in nfkd_form if not unicodedata.combining(c)])
$$ language plpythonu;
```

And I apply it to a column with:

```
SELECT remove_accents(city) FROM info_geo
```

Getting just null values. The column city is of varchar type. Why am I getting null values and how could I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a Python function inside the UDF. Either add a call of the function or write it as a scalar expression:

```
create function remove_accents(accented_string varchar)
returns varchar
immutable
as $$
  import unicodedata
  nfkd_form = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', accented_string)
  return u"".join([c for c in nfkd_form if not unicodedata.combining(c)])
$$ language plpythonu;
```